# How to omit certain tag from (% cache %)

Tags: templating, cache, plugin-freeform

How can I omit a certain tag from being cached?

I have a large page with a fair few queries but halfway down I am loading in a Freeform Form field which cannot be cached. But I'd like all of the content below it to be..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, the vanilla `{% cache %}` tag doesn't have a way to escape or ignore certain content.

The obvious workaround is to have more than one `{% cache %}` tag, where the content that *shouldn't* be cached sits between/outside those tags.

If you can't do that, another option is to use *output buffering* and injection. Basically, you cache whatever you need to cache, but `{% set %}` the output to a variable, rather than rendering it immediately. The important bit: Inside the content that you cache, you put some sort of placeholder value where you want the un-cached content to render. This placeholder can be whatever you want, but make it something that isn't likely to also appear in the actual content (e.g. `"%%%foobarbaz%%%"`). 
Then, `{% set %}` the un-cached content to a variable also – and finally, when you print the cached content, you use the `|replace` filter to replace the placeholder value in the *cached* content with the variable containing the *un-cached* content. Something like this:

```
{# Set the cached content to a variable #}
{% set cachedContent %}
    {% cache globally using key craft.request.path %}

        {# A bunch of taxing queries here #}
        <p>I am content.</p>

        {# Injection point for un-cached data #}
        %%%foobarbaz%%%

        <p>I am more content.</p>

    {% endcache %}
{% endset %}

{# Set the uncached content to a variable #}
{% set uncachedContent %}
    <p>I am some content that never is cached wooooo</p>
{% endset %}

{# Print the whole thing #}
{{ cachedContent|replace('%%%foobarbaz%%%', uncachedContent)|raw }}
```

Finally, [there's a plugin](https://github.com/benjamminf/craft-nocache) which may work for you.